# Custom Leaflet Tile Layer from 0.7.7 to 1.2.0

Tags: javascript, leaflet

I am moving some legacy code from Leaflet 0.7.7 to Leaflet 1.2.0. There is a custom TileLayer that is used that overrides getTileUrl(). In 1.2.0 the coordinates are scaled to half of 0.7.7. Which poses a problem for querying tiles with the service.

Here is the existing implementation of getTileUrl():

```
getTileUrl: function (tilePoint) {
    var imgType = "png",
        yHex = tilePoint.y.toString(0x10),
        xHex = tilePoint.x.toString(0x10),
        yPath = 'R' + this.padString(yHex, 8, '0').toUpperCase(),
        xPath = 'C' + this.padString(xHex, 8, '0').toUpperCase() + '.' + imgType,
        z = (tilePoint.z + 1),
        zL = 'L'+ (z<10?'0':'')+ z,
        final_url = this._url +zL+"/"+ yPath + "/" + xPath;

    return final_url;
}
```

Just doubling the x and y values does not work. Is there some mechanism in Leaflet to correct for this such as a multiplier for internal coordinates? Having trouble finding good resources for moving things like this from 0.7.7 to 1.2.0.

Here is an example:

In 0.7.7 I use center position [38.854699, -94.797763]

This has the tilePoint being {x: 7755, y: 12540, ...}

While in 1.2.0 with the same center position the point is {x: 3877, y: 6270,...}

So its a clear halving of the old values that were used in 0.7.7.

Comment: It would probably help if you could provide expected URL with given `tilePoint` input, and what is the "wrong" result.

Comment: Cannot reproduce your issue: http://playground-leaflet.rhcloud.com/seno/1/edit?html,output

Comment: @ghybs Any idea why it is halved for me? Some config? My main question is how this could/can be adjusted in Leaflet.

Comment: Could be related to retina or zoom offset. If you need further help, you have to provide more info.

Answer (score 0):

> This has the tilePoint being {x: 7755, y: 12540, ...}
>
> While in 1.2.0 with the same center position the point is {x: 3877, y: 6270,...}

If you look closely, those coordinates are doubled. That means there's an off-by-one error in the zoom level (because the `x` and `y` tile coordinates basically double for every zoom level). You should try removing the `z = (tilePoint.z + 1)` offset, or otherwise fiddle with it to see if the tile coordinates snap in place.